# How to find the original position in a DataTable from a filtered DataView

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010, datatable, dataview

I want to find a particular ID in a DataTable, I am using a DataView to filter the results, but how do I know which row in the original table the filter view corresponds to? Any ideas? In know I could use LINQ but I don't think this would help either?

```
        Dim dt As New DataTable
        Dim dv As New DataView(dt)
        dv.RowFilter = "ID = 123"
        If dv.Count = 1 Then
            'which datarow in the original datatable is this?
        End If
```

**EDIT**

I want to avoid having to loop through the DataTable to find this:

```
        For r As Integer = 0 To dt.Rows.Count - 1
            If CInt(dt.Rows(r).Item("ID")) = 123 Then
                Debug.WriteLine("Found it at row " + r.ToString)
                Exit For
            End If
        Next
```

Comment: Unless there's a unique identifier in the row, I'm not sure that you can...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nothing could be easier:

```
Dim dr As DataRow = dv(0).Row
```

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datarowview.row%28v=VS.100%29.aspx

Edit: According to your comment, you could use following to get the index of the row

```
Dim rowIndex As Int32 = -1
For i As Int32 = 0 To dr.Table.Rows.Count - 1
    If dr.Table.Rows(i)("ID").Equals(dr("ID")) Then
        rowIndex = i
        Exit For
    End If
Next
```

Or in this shorter way:

```
Dim rowIndex As Int32 = dr.Table.Rows.IndexOf(dr)
```

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datarowcollection.indexof.aspx

Comment: Yes that returns the DataRow but I want to know which row number (ordinal) that row is in the DataTable.

Comment: @Matt: edited my answer, but why do you need the RowIndex? It shouldn't matter normally.

Comment: Ah lovely thanks. I am creating a data class that hides the actual table from the calling at so if it wants to update the row with ID = 123 the calling app and the class do not know where that is in the table.

Comment: @Matt: I still don't understand for what calling app and the class need to know the row-index. `DataAdapter.Update(DataTable)` or `DataAdapter.Update(DataRow)` works without any index.

Comment: Well the calling app is in VB6 which doesn't know anything about datarows